# mkdir is not working with sudo and shell option

Tags: sudo

One of the application trying to create directory failing with the below error on Linux machine:

**$  /usr/bin/sudo -su oracle /bin/sh -c '/bin/mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/test12'**

/bin/mkdir: missing operand
Try `/bin/mkdir --help' for more information.

unix user has the sudo access on the oracle and which is working perfect on the other machine.

Comment: On which OS/distro?  Also, is that command **exactly** what you're doing, or have you helpfully interpolated some variable substitutions or similar for us?

Comment: For the command provides, this works as expected on my CentOS system.

Comment: Looks like a quoting issue, for sure. My guess: Ubuntu, using /bin/dash?

Comment: the "sh -c" trick is only needed if you use shell output to write with '>', '>>' or '2>'

Answer (score 0):

Try simply (/bin/sh is not needed at all):

```
sudo -su oracle /bin/mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/test12
```

May be your problem is caused by qoutes handled too early. If so, it may be solved by escaping: \'

Comment: you have to protect your command, though : sudo -su oracle "/bin/mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/test12"